# jQuery - is triggering ajax on click to work sequentially on database reliable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, click, onclicklistener

Suppose I have 4 radio buttons in a page and clicking on any of them triggers an ajax call so that the value of the radio button can be saved in database.

Suppose the user clicks on the first `radio` button, so an ajax call will be triggered that will save in database the value 1.

While this call is not yet finished, he clicks on the 2nd `radio` button (with value 2), so another ajax call is triggered.

There is no guarantee that the database column will have the value 2 (or **is there any ?**). Because the first call may not be finished while the second one might have been finished with database column finally containing the value 1 instead of 2.

The user can click as many times as he wishes. *What is the way so that the  value from the last radio button which is clicked on will be  stored in database?* Using `async:false` in the ajax configuration will be of no use , I think. Code follows :

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="options" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="options" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="options" value="4" />
```

JS:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){

        $radio=$(this);
        if($radio.is(':checked')) {
            var value_found = $radio.val().trim();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "my_url",
                data: "value_found=" + value_found,
                success: function (response) {

                },
                error: function (response) {

                }

            });
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it more reliable is to disable the fields, after a click, and wait until you get a response back from your ajax call to re-enable them. This way, you should not have to worry about competing calls.

```
 <input class="example" type="radio" name="options" value="1" />
 <input class="example" type="radio" name="options" value="2" />
 <input class="example" type="radio" name="options" value="3" />
 <input class="example" type="radio" name="options" value="4" />



 $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){

    $('.example').prop("disabled",true);

    $radio=$(this);
    if($radio.is(':checked')) {
        var value_found = $radio.val().trim();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my_url",
            data: "value_found=" + value_found,
            success: function (response) {},
            error: function (response) {},
            complete: function(response){
                $('.example').prop("disabled",false);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: How can a non-technical use understand that ?

Comment: How can a non-technical **user**   understand that ?

Comment: @Istiaque Ahmed I Added an example to make it clearer